# Assign octal/hex declared INT/UINT to another variable

Tags: c++, winapi, int, octal, uint

My **WIN32** (C++) code has a UINT lets call it **number**.
The value of this UINT (or INT doesn't matter) start with a **0** and is recognized as an **octal** value. It's possible to use the standart operators and the value will keep the octal-system. The same is possible with hex (with foregoing 0x).
The problem is I have to use the Value of **number** in a buffer to calculate with it without changing the value of **number**. I can assign a value like 07777 to buffer on declaration line but if use an operation like **buffer = number** the value in buffer is recognized on decimal base.

Anybody has a solution for me?

Comment: @juanchopanza: You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @KeithThompson I can't figure out what the question is. Feel free to post an answer.

Comment: why can I use the operation number++ and it counts like ...6 -> 7 -> 10 -> 11 -> 12... ? If there is no difference how is it possible? Could you give me a hint, please? *edit* to complete... if I assign buffer = number with a value of 77 and use the operation buffer++ it count 77 -> 78 -> 79...

Comment: "the value will keep the octal-system" is just baloney.  Have you configured your debugger to display certain variables in octal?

Answer (score 7):

There's no such thing in C as an "octal value". Integers are stored in binary.

For example, these three constants:

- `10`
- `012`
- `0xA`

all have exactly the same type and value. They're just different notations -- and the difference exists *only* in your source code, not at run time. Assigning an octal constant to a variable doesn't make the variable octal.

For example, this:

```
int n = 012;
```

stores the value *ten* in `n`. You can print that value in any of several formats:

```
printf("%d\n", n);
printf("0%o\n", n);
printf("0x%x\n", n);
```

In all three cases, the stored value is converted to a human-readable sequence of characters, in decimal, octal, or hexadecimal.

> Anybody has a solution for me?

No, because there is no actual problem.

(Credit goes to juanchopanza for mentioning this in a comment.)